# Webkit resets <details> ascendants to default box model

Tags: html, css, webkit

It seems to me like Webkit bug, but I am not sure. Despite the fact the `<details>` element has got correct `border-box` value, shadow DOM somehow resets all back to default `content-box`. Firefox is consistent. IE/Edge does not support `<details>` yet.

Is it a bug, or expected behaviour?

[See the demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Kout/pen/VWepRX)

Comment: If you set `*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }` instead, it works just fine, so I guess it is an _inherit_ issue, where the cascading inheritance fails somewhere

Comment: Whoa, even if you write `details {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
details * {
  box-sizing: inherit !important;
}`, it doesn't work. This is screwy. Surely Chrome knows what `inherit` means?

Comment: @MrLister Well, not when it comes to the `<details>` element :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug and you can read about it here:

- [https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=589475&q=details box-sizing](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=589475&q=details%20box-sizing&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)
- https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/9535

So you need to either revert to the *older* way to preset `box-sizing`

```
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

or set it explicit to `details`

Comment: Thank you, I wasn’t able to find it anwhere, so almost reported a bug ‒ which has been already reported.

My choice is to set it explicit to `details` (at least in this case).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than switch to the old way of targeting every element is to just target the children of details. This will still allow you to target reset components with the exception of the details, which don't work anyway. This can be done with:

`details > * { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: Which is the other possibility described by@LGSon, as far as I understand. And the way I used in my case in the end. I added simply this rule:
`details {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

It should be inherited by descendants as well, or am I wrong?